# Confused about constant objects C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm confused about constant objects in C++

When we have passed a  constant object/ reference of a const object  is that mean that we cannot edit the **attribute values** of  that object ?

or if its not whats the mean or **`constant`** in that is it 'refer' object' or 'attributes'

also when we return a constant object

declaring the function like

```
return_type function_name(parameters) const
{

}
```

the `const` keyword is at end of the function is it syntax ? and why if we return a `const` object shouldn't it be like follows

```
const return_type function_name(parameters) 
{

}
```

Sorry if its a noob question ;)

Comment: Read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html). It will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax:

```
return_type function_name(parameters) const
{

}
```

Indicates that `function_name()` may be invoked for an instance of the class that is const. It doesn't have any effect on the const-ness of the return value.

```
const return_type function_name(parameters)
{

}
```

...indicates that the value being returned from `function_name()` is const (and says nothing about the const-ness of the object having its member function called.)

Comment: thanks in what kind of scenarios that we should make the function 'constant' ?

Comment: @Sundantha In scenarios where you want to invoke the method on a constant instance. From another viewpoint, all methods that don't change the objects state should be constant.

Answer (score 3):

> When we have passed a constant object/ reference of a const object is that mean that we cannot edit the attribute values of that object ?

Yes. If the function is `const`, then the function cannot modify any non-mutable fields on the class. (Or call any other non-const method on the class).

> and why if we return a const object shouldn't it be like follows

Because the return type can be constant too. Consider the following:

```
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
    std::string data;
public:
    void SetData(const std::string& content)
    {
        data.assign(content);
    }
    const std::string& GetData() const //Note that the function is const, and so
    {                                  //is the reference it returns.
        return data;
    }
};
```

Note that we are returning a `const` reference to the internal member. If we returned a non `const` reference, than someone would be able to use the reference to modify the private member of the class, in this case `MyClass::data`.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively the added const changes the first "hidden" parameter of the method from `ClassType * const this` to `const ClassType * const this`.